# How about the Asp.net processes and threads and apppools?

Tags: asp.net, iis, multithreading

as i understand, when i load a asp.net .aspx page on the (iis)server, it's processed via the w3p.exe process.
But when iis gets multiple requests, are they all processed by the same w3p process?
And does this process automaticly use all my processors and cores?

And after that: when i start i new thread in my page, this thread still works when the pages is already served to the client.
Where does this thread live? also in the w3p.exe process?

And what if i assign another apppool to my site, what does that do?

Michel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS creates a separate worker process (w3wp.exe on Windows Server or aspnet_wp.exe on Windows XP) for each App Pool. If you create multiple App Pools it will create multiple worker processes. When a page gets multiple requests, yes, they are processed by multiple threads in the same worker process. Each thread can run on a separate processor or core, so yes. When you start a new thread manually it's no different - yes, it's in the same worker process.